# SQL Trigger - After Insert - Update statement and RAISERROR not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

I have a problem with a SQL trigger. It is an "AFTER INSERT" trigger. It works for every IF EXISTS block, except for the one with the update and raise error combinations as shown below. It either updates and moves on or stops and doesn't update.

Code: (where I left off - multiple different attempts at it and they all failed)

```
   IF EXISTS ( SELECT
                    [RPS].[Slip]
               FROM
                     [DC].[dbo].[Slips] AS [RPS]
               WHERE
                     [RPS].[Slip] = @ps
                     AND [RPS].[Status] = 0 )
               BEGIN    
                    BEGIN TRAN;
                          UPDATE
                                [DC].[dbo].[Slips]
                          SET
                                [Slip].[Status] = 1
                          FROM
                                [DC].[dbo].[Slips]
                          WHERE
                                [Slips].[Slip] = @ps;

                         SET @msg = ' ' + @NewLine + 'Inv. Decremented - Rollback' + @NewLine + 'Contact HD.' + @NewLine;

                         RAISERROR (@msg,16,1); 
                         COMMIT TRAN;
                         RETURN;
                END;
```

The goal is to update the table to a status of 1 when the IF EXISTS is caught and fire the RAISERROR. The RAISERROR is picked up by the java code and stops the processing from occurring. If I take the update out, the trigger raises the error and stops. If I take the raise error out, the trigger updates but moves on - and I don't want that... I want my cake and eat it too!

Thoughts?

Comment: Triggers start an implicit transaction, so your explicit transaction in the trigger is actually a nested one. SQL Server does not honor nested transactions and it is likely something funky is happening there. I would just remove your explicit transaction and see if that works for you.

Comment: Correction to the above comment.  It isn't that SQL Server "does not honor nested transactions" but the semantics may be a little different than what you expect.  SQL Server keeps track of the nesting level in `@@trancount` and only the outer `commit` (the one that causes `@@trancount` to go from 1 to 0) will actually commit the transaction.  A rollback (without a savepoint) will however rollback a transaction taking `@@trancount` to 0.

Comment: The `BEGIN TRAN` is superfluous.  It may be safely removed without affecting the behavior of the trigger which as @JohnSpecko points out already has an implicit transaction.  I do not expect this to fix whatever problem you are having however.  Does [DC].[dbo].[Slips] have an update trigger and does that update trigger have a `ROLLBACK` statement in it by any chance?  What could be going on is that `ROLLBACK` is rolling back everything including all nested transactions, including your work.

Comment: [DC].[dbo].[Slips] has no triggers

Comment: @dot3tech Please see my revised answer below.

Comment: Thanks @KenClement, my comment was a little oversimplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the update to the underlying triggered table while allowing the update to the Slips table you will need an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, a `VIEW`, and an ownership chain to prevent direct modification of the underlying table by users or their application code.  You cannot get there using a traditional `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for the reasons mentioned previously in the comments namely because both the triggering insert and the triggered update are wrapped in the same transaction, they must either both take effect or have neither take effect.  You cannot commit only part of a transaction and a nested transaction is part of the outermost transaction it is contained within.

Now for the solution...

**Part 1 - The View**
Create a view with the same column structure and naming as the table that has the insert trigger that is giving you all this trouble.  Something of the form:

```
CREATE VIEW [same-name-as-the-table-you-are-using]
AS
    SELECT <list-all-columns-explicitly-please-dont-use-star>
    FROM <original-table-with-slightly-different-name-now>
```

If the original table is named `XXX` then rename it something like `XXX_SINK` and use `XXX` for the view.  The users and application developers should consider this view the "table" they are using.

**Part 2 - The Ownership Chain**
An ownership chain is established in SQL Server when a referencing object and a referenced object have the same owner.  When a different party (not the owner) accesses the referencing object (in this case the view) the permissions for that party are evaluated against the referencing object as usual but are ***not evaluated*** against the referenced object (in this case the table).  This has been a feature of SQL Server since its beginning but is not known or well-understood by a number of SQL developers.  You can get more information about [ownership chains here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx).

You will want to deny permissions to the user base to the table and grant them to the view.  This means users can only insert or update rows through the view and not directly into the table.  This is important because you don't want them bypassing what you will do in the next part...

**Part 3 - The INSTEAD OF Trigger**
Create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view.  The syntax is just like that of an `AFTER` trigger except the words `INSTEAD OF` appears in place of `AFTER` and that no insert operation has occurred yet at the point it is fired and unless the trigger itself effects an update on the "sink" table, no update will be performed at all.  This trigger can mix and match whatever it wishes.  Like the `AFTER` trigger there is an implied transaction but only explicit data modification operations in the trigger itself will be performed.

Remember that the trigger has to explicitly perform the `insert` into the underlying sink table.  The rows to be inserted can be retrieved from the `inserted` special table just like in the case of the `AFTER` trigger.  Remember that there may (as far as SQL Server is concerned at least) be more than one row to be inserted (in fact there can be zero rows in the case of a zero-row insert statement).  You will need to decide whether or not to allow the good rows or deny insertion of all the rows.  Given your requirements, I suspect the later.

As a matter of sound database design, I would strongly recommend against -

1. The trigger restricting inserts to single rows, and
2. Using any form of cursor inside the trigger to deal with multi-row inserts.  Use set-oriented DML instead.

Even though the current application may only insert rows one at a time, the database should not impose such a restriction.

A reasonable `RAISERROR` (that is one with sensible severity and state values) will not cause anything to be aborted or rolled back.

Doing these things in this combination should produce the result you desire.